# Need help visualizing orthogonal projection in a picture

Tags: calculus, vectors

[image]

I basically need help with a) and b)

I know that $proj_{d}f=\frac{f\cdot d}{|d|^2}\cdot d$

and $proj_{d}b=\frac{b\cdot d}{|d|^2}\cdot d$

not exactly sure where to go from here

Also what is the difference between orthogonal projection (in part a) vs just regular projection (in part b)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll answer $\text{p}_df$ case, because $\text{p}_db$ case is exactly the same.

Since $f=d+e$ and $d\perp e$...

$$
\Bbb p_df=\frac{f\cdot d}{|d|^2}=\frac{(d+e)\cdot d}{|d|^2}d=\frac{d\cdot d}{|d|^2}d+\frac{e\cdot d}{|d|^2}d=d
$$